# Could not Resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using viewname

Tags: django-rest-framework

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.formatters.html import HtmlFormatter
from pygments import highlight


LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]

class Classname(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='fab')
    highlighted = models.TextField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    lexer = get_lexer_by_name(self.class_name)
    options = self.class_name and {'class': self.class_name} or {}
    formatter = HtmlFormatter(full=True, **options)

    self.highlighted = highlight(self.class_name, lexer, formatter)
    super(Classname, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py:

```
from django.forms import widgets
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Classname

class ClassSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='fab-highlight', format='html')
    class Meta:
        model = Classname
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'class_name', 'highlight',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fab = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='user-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'fab',)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^class/$', views.ClassList.as_view()),
    url(r'^class/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ClassDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^section/$', views.SectionList.as_view()),
    url(r'^section/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.SectionDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^teacher/$', views.TeacherList.as_view()),
    url(r'^teacher/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.TeacherDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^attend/$', views.AttendanceList.as_view()),
    url(r'^attend/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AttendanceDetail.as_view()),
]
```

When I changed my serializers.py file and try to add HyperLinked as per the tutorial then I got the above error, I'm not using ViewSets and Routers. I don't know what's the problem b'coz I've checked my url's and views everything seems to be fine.

I'm confused, Please help me to find and fix the issue....
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: What do your urls look like? That's going to be the key to fixing this, as it provides the information about the `view_name` and the arguments it is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The exact issue is that I'm using namespace in urls and I've used it in my project level urls.py file also. So in the views file I have to follow django-namespacing like this:

```
'users': reverse('student:user-list', request=request, format=format),
```

while `'student'` is the namespace that I've used in my project level urls like:

```
url(r'^stu/', include('app.urls', namespace = 'student'),
```